# display team name and parent name using sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

i have two tables

Teams table

```
id               name
1                A
2                B
3                B1
4                B2
```

Team_mapping table

```
id              team_id        parentid
1               1              0
2               2              0
3               3              2
4               4              2
```

display should be like this

```
 Team Name        Parent Name
 A                   - 
 B                   -
 B1                  B
 B2                  B
```

Please help me to write a sql query output same as above display

Comment: What was your attempt ?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` . . . and then `JOIN` again.

Comment: Can one team have two parents?

Comment: at present request  one team have one parent only

Comment: @user3101664 see my answer to make them arbitrarily deep  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43623490/124486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is use `left join`, and join `teams` twice:

```
select
    coalesce(t1.name, '-') "Team Name", coalesce(t2.name, '-') "Parent Name"
from team_mapping tm
left join teams t1 on tm.team_id = t1.id
left join teams t2 on tm.parentid = t2.id
```

then you can use subquery in `select` statement:

```
select
    coalesce((select t.name from teams t where t.id = tm.team_id), '-') "Team Name",
    coalesce((select t.name from teams t where t.id = tm.parentid), '-') "Parent Name"
from team_mapping tm
```

*Edit:* Previous first answer's `join` is incorrect, it should be `left join` in case of there is no parentid in table `teams`. Besides, for `null` s, use `coalesce` to convert to `-`.

[***Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2f91a/1) in sqlfiddle.

Comment: @user3101664 Updated some description, please check it again.

Comment: Thanks, both query works well, i need some additional column should be display that is team.id, team_mapping.id.. the same way should i use postgresql DB?

Comment: If you want to fetch `team.id` and `team_mapping.id` as well, just use first query, and add the `id`s in select statement. @user3101664

Comment: @EvanCarroll U're right!!! But if op just want parent, this will work. I have to admit I did not think more. :(

Comment: Thank you very much @Forward

Comment: @EvanCarroll, could you please tell me table structure for grand child

Comment: @user3101664 I show you that in my own answer. My answer provides for infinite hierarchy, nodes can have parents, that have parents, that have parents, that have parents. etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. There are two ways to do this,

1. [`ltree`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html)
2. hierarchical single table

Using the hierarchical single table is the best fit for you. It's a minor re-organization but it's much more semantic.

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
  id      serial PRIMARY KEY,
  parent  int    REFERENCES teams,
  name    text
);

INSERT INTO teams (id, parent, name) VALUES
  ( 1, null, 'A'  ),
  ( 2, null, 'B'  ),
  ( 3, 2,    'B1' ),
  ( 4, 2,    'B2' );
```

For an example of a recursive query for this..

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(id,name,parent) AS (
  SELECT t1.id, t1.name, ARRAY[]::text[]
  FROM teams AS t1
  WHERE parent IS NULL
  UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.id, t2.name, t1.parent || ARRAY[t1.name]
    FROM t AS t1
    JOIN teams AS t2
    ON t2.parent = t1.id
)
SELECT *
FROM t;

 id | name | parent 
----+------+--------
  1 | A    | {}
  2 | B    | {}
  3 | B1   | {B}
  4 | B2   | {B}
(4 rows)
```

This allows arbitrarily deep hierarchy.

```
INSERT INTO teams (id, parent, name) VALUES
  ( 5, 4, 'Deep' );
```

Running the same query as above,

```
 id | name | parent 
----+------+--------
  1 | A    | {}
  2 | B    | {}
  3 | B1   | {B}
  4 | B2   | {B}
  5 | Deep | {B,B2}
(5 rows)
```